# Serializing F# discriminated unions with protobuf

Tags: f#, protobuf-net

Is there some way to get protobuf to serialize/deserialize F#'s discriminated unions?

I'm trying to serialize messages with protobuf. Messages are F# records and discriminated unions.

Serialization seems to work fine for records but I cannot get it to work with discriminated unions.

In the following piece of code the tests testMessageA and testMessageB are green. The test testMessageDU is red.

```
module ProtoBufSerialization

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework

open ProtoBuf

type MessageA = {
  X: string;
  Y: int;
}

type MessageB = {
  A: string;
  B: string;
}

type Message =
| MessageA of MessageA
| MessageB of MessageB

let serialize msg =
  use ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()
  Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, msg, PrefixStyle.Fixed32)
  ms.ToArray()

let deserialize<'TMessage> bytes =
  use ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer=bytes)
  Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<'TMessage>(ms, PrefixStyle.Fixed32)

[<Test>]
let testMessageA() =
  let msg = {X="foo"; Y=32}
  msg |> serialize |> deserialize<MessageA> |> should equal msg

[<Test>]
let testMessageB() =
  let msg = {A="bar"; B="baz"}
  msg |> serialize |> deserialize<MessageB> |> should equal msg

[<Test>]
let testMessageDU() =
  let msg = MessageA {X="foo"; Y=32}
  msg |> serialize |> deserialize<Message> |> should equal msg
```

I tried adding different attributes like ProtoInclude and KnownType on type Message, CLIMutable on types MessageA and MessageB,... but nothing seems to help.

I'd prefer not having to map my DUs to classes to get serialization to work...

Comment: I genuinely don't know how F# represents those, in terms of what protobuf-net will see at runtime. If there is an obvious "fix" here (at the library level), I will be happy to take a look - but I'd need to dig a bit into what F# does here.

Comment: Afaik F# (always?) creates class hierarchies for discriminated unions. That's why I was hoping that I could use ProtoInclude attributes. Having looked at it in the decompiler now it looks like adjustments in the lib might be necessary to get this working.. :( unless someone comes up with a less obvious way to make it work. I uploaded the decompiled code here: http://codepad.org/DB0CQU4K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played with your very helpful generated output, and it looks like *basically* everything works - *except* the `Message.MessageA` sub-types. These *very nearly* work - they are essentially the same as the "auto-tuple" code (a constructor that matches all members), except that auto-tuples doesn't currently apply to sub-types.

I *think* it should be possible to tweak the code to work automatically, by extending the auto-tuple code to work in this scenario (I'm trying to think of any possible bad side-effects of that, but I'm not seeing any). I don't have a specific time-frame, as I need to balance time between multiple projects and a full-time day-job, and a family, and volunteer work, and (etc etc).

In the short term, the following C# is sufficient to make it work, but I don't expect this will be an attractive option:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Message).GetNestedType("MessageA")]
                .Add("item").UseConstructor = false;
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Message).GetNestedType("MessageB")]
                .Add("item").UseConstructor = false;
```

As an aside, the attributes here are unhelpful and should be avoided:

```
| [<ProtoMember(1)>] MessageA of MessageA
| [<ProtoMember(2)>] MessageB of MessageB
```

If they did anything, they would be duplicating the intent of `<ProtoInclude(n)>`. If it is *more convenient* to specify them there, that might be interesting, though. But what I find *really* interesting about that is that the F# compiler completely ignores the `AttributeUsageAttribute`, which for `[ProtoMember]` is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field,
    AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ProtoMemberAttribute {...}
```

Yes the F# compiler clearly stuck that (illegally) on a method:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.UnionCase, 0)]
public static ProtoBufTests.Message NewMessageA(ProtoBufTests.MessageA item)
```

naughty F# compiler!

Comment: Well yes it seems the Compiler did not check the AttributeUsage entry but it did not stick the attribute there .... stmax did here: `type Message =
| [<ProtoMember(1)>] MessageA of MessageA` ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig oh I realize that; I'm just of the opinion that the F# compiler should emit *at least* a warning about that (and ideally an error, although that may not be viable)

Comment: I got it working with the RuntimeTypeModel - though "Item" needs to be lowercase "item", otherwise it'll be null when deserializing. I think the reason is that Item only has a getter but no setter, while item is a field that it can read+write. Thanks for the workaround! Would be great to have native support for F#/DUs in the library one day. Here's the final code with all tests green: http://codepad.org/rZgV6HOQ

Comment: +1 And thanks @stmax for code dump. See riff and my conclusion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25206246/11635

Answer (score 3):

I spiked using `protobuf-net` for [event sourcing DUs](https://github.com/thinkbeforecoding/FsUno.Prod) and am very appreciative of [json.net v6's seamless support for DUs](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support).

The reasons I relented on my initial desire to use protobuf-net in preference are:

1. I never got to prove the perf gap I was seeking
2. My desire to be resilient against field renaming (relying on addressing being via `[<ProtoMember(n)>]`) in my message contracts are mitigated by the combination of:

   - field name aliasing (i.e. using attributed to tell F# to compile under the old name)
   - the ability to use the strengths of DUs Pattern matching to version events by adding in `EventXXXV2` alongside `EventXxx` in the same DU

And I didnt find a cleaner way than:

```
let registerSerializableDuInModel<'TMessage> (model:RuntimeTypeModel) =
    let baseType = model.[typeof<'TMessage>]
    for case in typeof<'TMessage> |> FSharpType.GetUnionCases do
        let caseType = case.Name |> case.DeclaringType.GetNestedType 
        baseType.AddSubType(1000 + case.Tag, caseType) |> ignore
        let caseTypeModel = model.[caseType]
        caseTypeModel.Add("item").UseConstructor <- false
    baseType.CompileInPlace()

let registerSerializableDu<'TMessage> () = registerSerializableDuInModel<'TMessage> RuntimeTypeModel.Default

registerSerializableDu<Message> ()
```

to address the need for `[<ProtoInclude(100, "ProtoBufTests+Message+MessageA")>]` cruft. (I'm still pondering whether what mix of F# and protbuf-net improvements would best address that)

A pretty important difference is lack of need for `[<ProtoContract; CLIMutable>]` sprinklage (in addition to the `ProtoInclude` and `ProtoMember` ones).

Code dump:

```ml
module FunDomain.Tests.ProtobufNetSerialization

open ProtoBuf
open ProtoBuf.Meta

open Swensen.Unquote
open Xunit

open System.IO
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

[<ProtoContract; CLIMutable>]
type MessageA = {
    [<ProtoMember(1)>] X: string;
    [<ProtoMember(2)>] Y: int option;
}

[<ProtoContract>]
[<CLIMutable>]
type MessageB = {
    [<ProtoMember(1)>] A: string;
    [<ProtoMember(2)>] B: string;
}

[<ProtoContract>]
type Message =
    | MessageA of MessageA
    | MessageB of MessageB

let serialize msg =
    use ms = new MemoryStream()
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, msg, PrefixStyle.Fixed32)
    ms.ToArray()

let deserialize<'TMessage> bytes =
    use ms = new MemoryStream(buffer=bytes)
    Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<'TMessage>(ms, PrefixStyle.Fixed32)

let registerSerializableDuInModel<'TMessage> (model:RuntimeTypeModel) =
    let baseType = model.[typeof<'TMessage>]
    for case in typeof<'TMessage> |> FSharpType.GetUnionCases do
        let caseType = case.Name |> case.DeclaringType.GetNestedType 
        baseType.AddSubType(1000 + case.Tag, caseType) |> ignore
        let caseTypeModel = model.[caseType]
        caseTypeModel.Add("item").UseConstructor <- false
    baseType.CompileInPlace()

let registerSerializableDu<'TMessage> () = registerSerializableDuInModel<'TMessage> RuntimeTypeModel.Default

registerSerializableDu<Message> ()

let [<Fact>] ``MessageA roundtrips with null`` () =
    let msg = {X=null; Y=None}
    let result = serialize msg
    test <@ msg = deserialize result @>

let [<Fact>] ``MessageA roundtrips with Empty`` () =
    let msg = {X=""; Y=None}
    let result = serialize msg
    test <@ msg = deserialize result @>

let [<Fact>] ``MessageA roundtrips with Some`` () =
    let msg = {X="foo"; Y=Some 32}
    let result = serialize msg
    test <@ msg = deserialize result @>

let [<Fact>] ``MessageA roundtrips with None`` () =
    let msg = {X="foo"; Y=None}
    let result = serialize msg
    test <@ msg = deserialize result @>

let [<Fact>] ``MessageB roundtrips`` () =
    let msg = {A="bar"; B="baz"}
    let result = serialize msg
    test <@ msg = deserialize result @>

let [<Fact>] ``roundtrip pair``() =
    let msg1 = MessageA {X="foo"; Y=Some 32}
    let msg1' = msg1 |> serialize |> deserialize
    test <@ msg1' = msg1 @>

    let msg2 = MessageB {A="bar"; B="baz"}     
    let msg2' = msg2 |> serialize |> deserialize
    test <@ msg2' = msg2 @>

let [<Fact>] many() =
    for _ in 1..1000 do
        ``roundtrip pair``()
```

Comment: Will edit in more but one thing to be aware of in the 'seamless' support is that field names of tuples are not serialized in the example. Not sure whether that applies to records too but my main point is to not just blindly use the OOTB support (doesnt change my general principle that [contextless processing is important](https://github.com/thinkbeforecoding/FsUno.Prod/issues/2#issuecomment-52162817))

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is something like this

```
    let typeModel = TypeModel.Create()
    let resultType = typedefof<Result>
    let resultNestedTypes = resultType.GetNestedTypes() |> Array.filter (fun x -> x.Name <> "Tags")
    for nestedType in resultNestedTypes do 
        let model = typeModel.Add( nestedType, true )
        model.UseConstructor <- false
        nestedType.GetFields( BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.GetField ) |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Name ) |> Array.sort |> model.Add |> ignore

        types.[ nestedType.Name ] <- nestedType
```

In my case `types` is dictionary of the union types built when app is launched. I would need to save the name in the message before the serialized data to be able to load it later.

This will work as long as only new fields are added, since each field becomes `item1`. If there's a need to delete fields I think it could be pretty easily expanded to take the field order number from the field name like so

```
type Result = 
    | Success of Item1: string * Item3:bool
    | Failure of string
```

And extract the number after Item, or whatever will work the best. There're numerous approaches.