# Problems roundtripping F# discriminated unions with Json.net

Tags: serialization, f#, json.net, ravendb

I have the following enum in F#

```
 type MyEnum = 
    | Value1
    | Value2
    | Value3
```

This is what the compiler generates when the code compiles

```
   [Serializable]
    [DebuggerDisplay("{__DebugDisplay(),nq}")]
    public class MyEnum : IEquatable<MyEnum>, IStructuralEquatable, IComparable<MyEnum>, IComparable, IStructuralComparable
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public bool IsValue1 { get; }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public bool IsValue2 { get; }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public bool IsValue3 { get; }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public int Tag { get; }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public static MyEnum Value1 { get; }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public static MyEnum Value2 { get; }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public static MyEnum Value3 { get; }

        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed int CompareTo(MyEnum obj);
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed int CompareTo(object obj);
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed int CompareTo(object obj, IComparer comp);
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed bool Equals(MyEnum obj);
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed bool Equals(object obj);
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed bool Equals(object obj, IEqualityComparer comp);
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed int GetHashCode();
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public override sealed int GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comp);

        public static class Tags
        {
            public const int Value1 = 0;
            public const int Value2 = 1;
            public const int Value3 = 2;
        }
    }
```

**Problem**
When the above enum type is used for serialization which requires non-static `set` for each property for deserialization, it fails. In fact I have used it with `RavenDB` and `Json.Net` serialization and I get the following

```
myenummember = {}
```

How do I effectively make use of F# enum types with serializers ?

Comment: That's a union type, not an enum. The following is an enum: `type MyEnum = Value1 = 0 | Value2 = 1 | Value3 = 2`

Comment: If you are trying to serialize a DU (what the example actually is), we had a very similar question recently here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884814/serializing-f-discriminated-unions-with-protobuf

Comment: What ildjarn said. 

In F# [.NET enum types](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/enum-types/) are 
completely different from [discriminated union types](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/), even though they look very similar syntax-wise.

Enums are just standard .NET enums, and are compatible with any serializer that understands them.
DUs on the other hand, are represented internally by a class with nested classes and will need special support from the serializer.

Here's a [good post](http://ikriv.com/dev/misc/fsharp/fs_enums.html) that explains the difference.

Comment: What json.net version ? 6.0.(3?) adds support (but there are weaknesses, see my answer). BTW you really really should show what you're doing codewise if you're going to treat us to a big dump of the compiled output, useful and all as that is

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try marking the type with the "Serializable" attribute. Also providing assignment for the pattern identifiers might help the compiler infer that it is a enum and not a sum type might help.

```
[<Serializable>]
type x =
  ABC = 1
| ABE = 2
```

Comment: -1 Should not make any difference - I don't use any such contraptions and json.net is pretty thorough in handling lots of different cases. (And I'll ask the OP for code which is what should have happened...)

Answer (score 2):

You can provide JsonConverter instances that know how to translate this back & forth.

Answer (score 2):

While Json.net 6.0(.1?) provides support for F# DUs, there are many weaknesses (some of which are mentioned in my answer and commentary in [@John Palmer's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884814/serializing-f-discriminated-unions-with-protobuf)).

[FsUno.Prod](http://thinkbeforecoding.github.io/FsUno.Prod/) incorporates a `Serialization.fs` (written by Jérémie Chassaing) which addresses these concerns and more [using the technique @Ayende Rahien mentions].

---

(At this very instant [my fork, FunDomain](https://github.com/bartelink/FunDomain) [includes some further extensions](https://github.com/bartelink/FunDomain/blob/6b7cbdfe1e4ea8c7f05c1c1391295ba5175332a2/FunDomain.Tests/SerializationFacts.fs#L58-L81)) [here](https://github.com/bartelink/FunDomain/blob/6b7cbdfe1e4ea8c7f05c1c1391295ba5175332a2/FunDomain.Persistence/Serialization.fs). (The changes will likely end up back in FsUno.Prod which should be considered the authoratative repo)