# How customize Json.NET to render inline a F# union type?

Tags: json, serialization, f#, json.net

If I have a record like this:

```
type Size =
    | H1
    | H2
    | H3
    | H4
    | H5

type Icon = {size:Size; title:string}
```

This render like this:

```
    "size" : {
      "Case" : "H1"
    },
    "title" : "hello"
```

How make Json.NET to render it like:

```
    "size" : "H1"
    "title" : "hello"
```

I call (F#) like this:

```
    Json.fromObj widget
```

No more configuration or setup of any kind (this is my first try with a Json library in .NET)

I have several of this type declarations + records, and only use for typesafe construction, but wish to serialize all inline

Comment: `{size=H1, title="Hello"}` isn't valid JSON, so it's difficult to answer the question. As which *valid* JSON should it render?

Comment: @mamcx - it's too few of details -  what JSON you get that you do not like, and what JSON you want. Also, update your question with how you call `SerializeObject`?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924976/problems-roundtripping-f-discriminated-unions-with-json-net