# Deserializing an F# discriminated union with protobuf-net

Tags: serialization, f#, protobuf-net, discriminated-union

Using the following SO answer as a guideline: [Serializing F# discriminated unions with protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884814/serializing-f-discriminated-unions-with-protobuf)
I have put together a way to serialize a simple F# discriminated union. Unfortunately I cannot get it to serialize the second case of the DU without throwing a `stackoverflow exception`. What am I doing wrong?

## CODE

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Collections.Generic

open ProtoBuf

[<ProtoContract>]
[<ProtoInclude(100, "Program+DU+Good")>]
[<ProtoInclude(200, "Program+DU+Bad")>]
type DU = 
    | Good of bool
    | Bad of int
with
    override this.ToString() =
        match this with
        | Good i -> i.ToString()
        | Bad s -> s.ToString()


[<ProtoContract; Serializable>]
type Person(name:string, age:int, du:DU) = 
    let mutable name = name
    let mutable age = age
    let mutable du = du

    new() = Person("",0,Good true)

    [<ProtoMember(1)>]
    member this.Name 
        with get() = name
        and set(v) = name <- v

    [<ProtoMember(2)>]
    member this.Age 
        with get() = age
        and set(v) = age <- v

    [<ProtoMember(3)>]
    member this.DU
        with get() = du
        and set(v) = du <- v

    override this.ToString() = this.Name + ", " + this.Age.ToString() + ", " + this.DU.ToString()


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    // typeof vs typedefof ?
    ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.[typeof<DU>.GetNestedType("Good")].Add("item").UseConstructor <- false
    ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.[typeof<DU>.GetNestedType("Bad")].Add("item").UseConstructor <- false
    //RuntimeTypeModel.Default.[typeof<DU>].CompileInPlace()    // doesn't seem to make any difference

    let p1 = Person("Sam", 38, Good false)
    let p2 = Person("Cand", 34, Bad 99)

    let filePath = @"C:\Temp\protocol.bin"

    if not (File.Exists filePath) then
        let fs = File.Create(filePath)
        fs.Close()

    use fileStream1 = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write)
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<Person>(fileStream1, p2)   // p1 does work because it uses the first case of the DU  
    fileStream1.Close()

    use fileStream2 = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    let result = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(fileStream2)      // stackoverflow exception ONLY for p2
    fileStream2.Close()

    printfn "%A" result
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Where does the exception happen? Stack?

Comment: The only output in Debug mode is: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.` As mentioned in code comments above, the exception is triggered on calling `Deserialize<Person>(fileStream2)`

Comment: What's the call stack at the moment of exception?

Comment: The call stack (Visual Studio, debug mode) is blank! It's kinda like its happening in code that my program has no meta-info about.

Comment: You might want to consider [FsPickler](https://nessos.github.io/FsPickler/benchmarks.html) - it's competitive with ProtoBuf on seralized size and performance, and supports F# types very well.